# Displaying Title on Coverflow Image Template for iphone

Tags: iphone, coverflow

I am using CoverFlow in my application ,it is working fine but, I need to display the title of image that appears to front in coverflow,To add images iam usinf following code...

```
loadImagesOperationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
 for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];
        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
          NSLog(@"my image name is %@",imageName);
        NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

        }

        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];
```

Can any one help me out.Below is the screenshot I would like to implement.

[image: ]![enter image description here]

Comment: label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 280, 145, 50)];
  label.opaque=YES;
  label.hidden=YES;
  label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
  label.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
  label.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
  label.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self addSubview:label]; do this in AFItemView class in - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame class

Comment: I have done with the lable, my app is crashing at      [coverImageName setObject:coverView.imageName forKey:coverNumber];with crash report ,
 '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: 0)'

Comment: arey yar u have to pass the image name from the CoverFlowViewController class na?see below answer.U have to change the method name as - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index named:(NSString*)imageName; from - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index; in AFOpenFlowView class.

Comment: Thanks alot!!! it is working!! I changed - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index to  - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index named:(NSString *)imageName....

Comment: @hai.what happen to your gmail?

Comment: its there but I am using less.Use webview to get the javascript data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9989/discussion-between-developer-and-rama-rao)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes.U have to pass like below:`

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forIndex:(int)index named:(NSString*)imageName{
    // Create a reflection for this image.
    UIImage *imageWithReflection = [image addImageReflection:kReflectionFraction];
    NSNumber *coverNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:index];
    [coverImages setObject:imageWithReflection forKey:coverNumber];
    [coverImageHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:image.size.height] forKey:coverNumber];
    [coverImageName setObject:imageName forKey:coverNumber];`

    // If this cover is onscreen, set its image and call layoutCover.
    AFItemView *aCover = (AFItemView *)[onscreenCovers objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
    if (aCover) {
        [aCover setImage:imageWithReflection originalImageHeight:image.size.height reflectionFraction:kReflectionFraction named:imageName];

        [self layoutCover:aCover selectedCover:selectedCoverView.number animated:NO];
    }
}`
```

and i pass the image name like below:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"cover_%d.jpg", i];UIImage* image_=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        CGFloat width = 290;
        CGFloat height = 200;

        CGSize newSize=CGSizeMake(width, height);
        [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[self imageWithImage:image_ scaledToSize:newSize] forIndex:i named:imageName];
        [imageName release];
        NSLog(@"%d is the index",i);

    }
    [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply take a label in method`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{}` for class AFItemView.m in openflow code and check in the class:AFOpenFlowView.m in method `- (void)centerOnSelectedCover:(BOOL)animated{}` set text as below`selectedCoverView.label.text=coverImagename;`.This worked for me.

Comment: Can I know what is coverImagename here? same as my imageName? I have declared property for imageName in my CoverFlowViewController  class,but it is nor appearing in AFOpenFlowView.m.

Comment: @Rama Rao - (void)centerOnSelectedCover:(BOOL)animated {
    CGPoint selectedOffset = CGPointMake(COVER_SPACING * selectedCoverView.number, 0);
    coverView=[[CoverFlowViewController alloc]init];
    selectedCoverView.lbl.text=coverView.imageName;
    NSLog(@" here image name is %@",selectedCoverView.lbl.text);

 [scrollView setContentOffset:selectedOffset animated:animated];
  }    the log is showing null value,title is not added to image.

Comment: check the below code:- (void)centerOnSelectedCover:(BOOL)animated {
 CGPoint selectedOffset = CGPointMake(COVER_SPACING * selectedCoverView.number, 0);
 NSNumber *coverNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedCoverView.number];
 NSString *coverImagename=[coverImageName objectForKey:coverNumber];
 selectedCoverView.label.text=coverImagename;
 selectedCoverView.label.hidden=NO; 
 [scrollView setContentOffset:selectedOffset animated:animated];
}

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this line,  NSString *coverImagename=[coverImageName objectForKey:coverNumber];is  coverImageName dictionary?